# Running git from node.js as a child process?

Tags: linux, node.js, git, ssh, debian

I am attempting to write a generic command-runner in Node.JS - however that's not massively important.
My setup is as follows:

1. I have a list of string commands that are executed using `child_process.exec` one after the other.
2. I want to run git from one of these commands, specifically a `pull`.
3. The location I am pulling from requires SSH authentication. HTTPS is not an option.
4. My private key is passphrased.
5. I am currently using `keychain` to manage `ssh-agent`.

When running `git pull` from the command line, it succeeds. When running my application as the logged-in user, it succeeds. However, when running my application using `forever`, it fails.

The error I receive is `Permission denied (publickey).`. I have tried calling `keychain` as part of my command, but I cannot get it to recognise the credentials.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I suppose you need to run `git pull` in interactive Bash shell for it to work with your `~/.ssh` keys, but Node's child process runs the command directly without any environment

Comment: Try running `bash -lic "git pull"`

Comment: Thanks @laggingreflex - when I attempt that `keychain` reports that it cannot find `id_rsa`. Running `keychain ...; git pull` in from `bash` causes the command to hang, presumably waiting for input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was taking the contents of `.bash_profile` and using that to set up `keychain` from my `exec`.

What I needed to do was:
`. $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh; git pull`

I found this out by looking up examples of how to use `keychain` with `bash` scripts.